# Get discount amount for customer group in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, catalog-rules

I have **customer group id**.

I need to get **sales rule** for this **customer group**.

And after that I want to **get discount amount** in % for this **sales rule**;

```
$customer_from_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer_from_db = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_from_session->getId());
$group_id = $customer_from_db->getGroupId();
```

And by `$group_id` I need to find actual discounts

**Much thanks!**

Comment: Just as a not ... you can get the customer group ID with `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()`

Comment: Do you want to get the discount amount for a single rule?

Comment: @sv3n yes, I want to get single sales rule applied to this customer group and discount amount for this rule

Comment: Please let me know if the code from below works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
$websiteId  = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$groupId    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$ruleName   = /* your rule name */;

$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')
    ->setValidationFilter($websiteId, $groupId);
$rules->addFieldToFilter('name', $ruleName);
$rules->getSelect()->limit(1);

$rule = $rules->getFirstItem();

echo $rule->getSimpleAction(); // by percent ...
echo $rule->getDiscountAmount(); // amount
```

---

**Edit:** to get all rules you can try this (not tested yet)

```
$websiteId  = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$groupId    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')
    ->setValidationFilter($websiteId, $groupId);

foreach ($rules->getItems() as $rule) {
    echo $rule->getSimpleAction(); // by percent ...
    echo $rule->getDiscountAmount(); // amount
}
```

Comment: What to do if I want to get all rules ?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: $rules->getItems() works

Comment: Do you know how to make smth like this for catalog rules ?

Comment: 1:.) update code for getItems ... if this isn't correct please suggest an edit. 2) catalogrule has bit different behavior ... if you need this, please post another question.

Comment: Ok, you are great coder !!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/178921/55255 can you answer my new question ?

Comment: It's on screen :) either later today it tomorrow.