# Get catalog rule discount amount for customer group in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have **customer group id**.

I need to get **catalog rule** for this **customer group**.

And after that I want to **get discount amount** in % for this **catalog rule**;

Now I make something like this:

```
    $group_id= Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $db = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM catalogrule 
              JOIN catalogrule_customer_group 
              ON catalogrule.rule_id = catalogrule_customer_group.rule_id
              WHERE catalogrule.is_active = 1
              AND catalogrule_customer_group.customer_group_id = {$group_id}
              ORDER BY catalogrule.sort_order
              LIMIT 1";
    $results = $db->fetchAll($query);
```

**Much thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect, but still better then a raw query ...

```
$groupId    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule_collection')->addIsActiveFilter();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array('group' => $resource->getTableName('catalogrule/customer_group')),
        'main_table.rule_id=group.rule_id',
        array('customer_group_id')
    )
    ->where('group.customer_group_id = ?', $groupId)
    ->order('sort_order ASC')
    ->limit(1);

$rule = $collection->getFirstItem();

var_dump(array(
    $rule->getData('name'),
    $rule->getData('simple_action'),
    $rule->getData('discount_amount')
));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hello again, please check my question ( https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183914/how-to-add-modules-page-to-admin-panel-and-call-particular-method-in-controller ). Can you advise how to solve it. Thanks!